# parameter is being passed in routing without passing any parameter in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on Angular project. I am routing from one page to another page. I have written two functions. In the first one I have passed queryParams while in the second function I have only routed to another function as follows.

```
onEdit(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
    this.router.navigate(['pages/details'], {queryParams: event.data});
}

addData() {
    this.router.navigate(['pages/details']);
}
```

but when i call this functions i get parameters in both functions

```
<nb-card-body>
    <button mat-button class="btn edit btn-success " style="margin-left: 400px;" (click)="addData()"><i class="nb-plus"></i></button>
    <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source" (edit)="onEdit($event)" (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)">
    </ng2-smart-table>
</nb-card-body>
```

when I call addData() in .html it will route to details page which as follow

```
export class DetailsComponent {
    data: any;
    isAddPage: boolean = true;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private service: SmartTableService, private router: Router) {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            this.data = params;
            console.log(params);
            if (this.data == null)
                this.isAddPage = true;
            else
                this.isAddPage = false;
        });
        console.log(this.data);
        console.log(this.isAddPage);
    }
}
```

though on addData() it should not pass any data but it giving me as follows in console

```
{}__proto__: constructor: ƒ Object()hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()toString: ƒ ()valueOf: ƒ valueOf()__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
details.component.ts:35 {}__proto__: Object
details.component.ts:36 false
```

any help?

Comment: Try `if (this.data === null)` read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162911/angular-2-what-differences-between-comparison-operators-and-in-ngif-dire

Comment: @Swoox its not working

Comment: @Swoox any help

Comment: @Melchia any help?